# Which implementations of the C programming language violate the following assumptions?

Tags: c, alignment, padding, abi

I'm trying to write a portable function that marshals binary formats into structures according to a formatting string not entirely unlike `scanf`. To do this, I make a couple of assumptions about the platform my code is running on:

1. This `structalign` macro portably finds the alignment of a scalar type.

   ```
   #define structalign(t) offsetof (struct{char pad; t var;}, var)
   ```
2. In a structure, the address of a member `t` is the next free address which is a multiple of `structalign(t)`.
3. The value of `structalign(t)` where `t` is a structure or union or array type is the maximum of `structalign(m)` where `m` is the type of a member of `t`.

On which platforms do these assumptions fail? Is any of them backed by the C standard, specifically C99? Are there better assumptions I can make?

Comment: It will fail if the member is a bit-field (UB) and probably also if the struct/union contains bit-fields. But it will probably not be an issue, since no sane person uses bit-fields when writing portable code (or anywhere else for that matter).

Comment: @Lundin Yeah, ok, point taken. I don't operate on bitfields. Disregard them for this question, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alignment is not addressed by C99.  It does not support *any* of your assumptions.  Implementations are allowed free reign to insert padding -- or not -- in `struct` representations between members and/or at the end, however they see fit.  The standard gives implementations enough freedom to serve the alignment requirements of their target environments, but it provides no basis to support *any* behavior intended to probe alignment requirements.  In particular, their is *no* inherent relationship between the offset of a `struct` member and the optimal alignment of objects of its type.

Although your code probably does correctly determine alignment when used with many implementations, under many conditions, that code, or anything based on the same concept, would surely fail when compiled in a mode that caused all `struct` representations to be packed without padding.  Such a mode is provided as an option by many compilers and could in principle be the default mode for some compilers.

Since anything you might do to evaluate data type alignment involves implementation-defined and/or unspecified behavior, I would recommend that you separate such mechanisms from the main code, and instead put them in your build system (supposing that you are using an adaptive multi-platform build system such as CMake or the GNU Autotools).

Comment: I'm sure that you can break my code with application of `#pragma pack` and friends. I assume that the structure does not use weird constructs like bitfields or packed structure members. Do you know any implementations where my assumptions are incorrect in general? I understand that they are probably not backed by the C standard.

Comment: Well, you *asked* whether they are backed by the standard.  In any case, I'm not talking about `#pragma pack` or anything else that involves modifying your code.  Your code breaks with GCC if the `-fpack-struct` compiler option is used, and many compilers offer such an option.  I have no personal knowledge of an implementation for which your code is broken by default, but I bet I could find one if I looked hard enough.

Comment: Code generated with `-fpack-struct` is incompatible to any other code because it destroys ABI compatibility. The question about C99 was only one out of three and one of the lesser interesting. I'm actually more interested in whether there are any existing platforms that pad members in a structure by a different way.

Comment: Also answered: there are *no* "better" assumptions you can make about alignment, in that the standard does not support any assumptions at all about that topic.  And: there are *many* platforms on which your code breaks under platform-specific circumstances.  Whether those particular circumstances include any you care about is a separate question, which you have not given us sufficient information to address.

Comment: Can you give me some examples for such platforms so I can look into this?

Comment: I did.  GCC with `-fpack-struct`.  There's also ICC with `-fpack-struct`.  Also CL.EXE with `/Zp`.  I'd be inclined to suspect that some implementations for embedded microcontrollers pack `struct`s by default, but I have no specific example.

Comment: If you compile with `-fpack-struct`, my assumptions probably still apply, too, as `structalign` macro would return 1 for every type, so if you compile with that option would not break my code, although this is a really stupid idea. Notice that on microcontrollers specifically you usually have to use padding as they often can't do misaligned memory access. You can reduce the amount of memory wasted by padding to a negligible amount anyway by rearranging structure members.

Comment: If you compile with `-fpack-struct` or an equivalent on any platform for which the natural alignment of any type is other than 1, then your assumption (1) certainly fails.  You are right, though that your assumptions (2) and (3) hold in that particular case.  Whether that presents a problem for your particular usage on any platform you care about is a different question.  If it *were* a problem, then I'm sure that users who were bitten by it would fail to see the humor in being called "stupid" for compiling with options your code did not anticipate.

Comment: The option `-fpack-struct` breaks ABI compatibility. Unless your code is completely self-contained in that it doesn't use any library functions at all, it won't work. Nobody with a sane mind would compile code like that and it's not my jobs to support people who do stupid things. Do you know of any platforms where my assumptions break where the breakage is not caused by people breaking the ABI with flags like that?

Comment: `-fpack-struct` breaks ABI compatibility only with respect to `struct` definitions actually processed by the compiler and used by the program.  Its use does not inherently preclude calling library functions.  People *do* compile code with that option -- that's why some version of it is provided by so many compilers.  I cannot say, however, whether you are required to support such people.

Comment: In any event, I cannot specifically name a compiler that, when run with default options, would violate your assumptions.  It remains the case, however, that they are *assumptions* that you cannot prove valid for any given compiler and set of options without testing.  If that is the course you intend to take then yours is a tool I do not wish to use.

Comment: Thank you for the notice. You are not required to use my tool. You will be amazed at how much even more unportable code you can find!